# Android Application theme not being set on all activity's

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-preferences, android-theme

I have been working on implementing a theme changer in a current application.

I have a preferences screen set up which allows the user to choose between 2 themes, dark and light.

The activities I have are set up like this;

- Activity A is the main activity and starts Activity B and C.
- Both Activity B & C hold a ViewPager which load multiple fragments

Now I am running into problems with Activity A. It seem's to be applying the changed theme BUT only to the Action overflow (drop down box) on the ActionBar (screenshot below)

I am setting the set in the onCreate method of the activity.

[image: Action overflow in AB screenshot]

As you can see only the overflow has the light theme applied to it.

Here's my ThemeUtils class.

```
public class ThemeUtils
{
  public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
  public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 1;
  public final static int THEME_DARK = 2;

  private static int mTheme;

  /**
   * Sets the theme of the activity and restarts it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
   * @param activity Activity that initiates the theme change
   * @param theme An int value to identify which theme to change to - (use ThemeUtils constants)
   */
  public static void changeToTheme( final Activity activity, final int theme )
  {
    mTheme = theme;
    finishAndRestartActivity( activity );
  }

  /**
   * Sets the theme of the activity, according to the value of mTheme
   * @param activity The activity to set the theme to
   */
  public static void setTheme( final Activity activity )
  {
    switch ( mTheme )
    {
      case THEME_LIGHT:
        activity.setTheme( R.style.Result_Theme_Light );
        break;
      case THEME_DARK:
        activity.setTheme( R.style.Result_Theme_Dark );
        break;

      default:
      case THEME_DEFAULT:
        activity.setTheme( R.style.Result_Theme_Dark );
        break;
    }
  }

  public static int getTheme()
  {
    return mTheme;
  }

  public static boolean canSetThemeFromPrefs( final Activity activity )
  {
    boolean result = false;
    SharedPreferences prefMngr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( activity );
    if ( prefMngr.contains( "theme_pref" ) )
    {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static int getThemeFromPrefs( final Activity activity )
  {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( activity );
    final String themeFromPrefs = preferences.getString( "theme_pref", "theme_default" );
    if ( themeFromPrefs.equals( "theme_light" ) )
    {
      mTheme = THEME_LIGHT;
    }
    else if ( themeFromPrefs.equals( "theme_dark" ) )
    {
      mTheme = THEME_DARK;
    }
    else
    {
      mTheme = THEME_DEFAULT;
    }

    return getTheme();
  }

  public static int getThemeFromPrefs( final String key )
  {
    if ( key.equals( "theme_light" ) )
    {
      mTheme = THEME_LIGHT;
    }
    else if ( key.equals( "theme_dark" ) )
    {
      mTheme = THEME_DARK;
    }
    else
    {
      mTheme = THEME_DEFAULT;
    }

    return getTheme();
  }

  private static void finishAndRestartActivity( final Activity activity )
  {
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity( new Intent( activity, activity.getClass() ) );
  }
}
```

Any tips/thoughts?

Thanks,
Sam.